# how to insert affix navbar, and the nav fixed position

Tags: html

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="index.php"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home">       </span> Beranda</a></li>
        <li><a href="profile.php"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt"></span> Profil</a></li>
        <li><a href=><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-open"></span> Data Alumni</a>

    </ul>
</nav>
```

how to make affix navbar, while the underlying content can scroll

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to provide `position:fixed` to your `nav`. See the below snippet for better understanding.

> A fixed position element is positioned relative to the viewport, or the browser window itself. The viewport doesn't change when the window is scrolled, so a fixed positioned element will stay right where it is when the page is scrolled

```html
<nav style="position:fixed; top:0px; background-color: #ffffff; z-index: 30001; opacity: 1; filter: alpha(opacity=70);width:100%;">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="index.php"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home">       </span> Beranda</a></li>
        <li><a href="profile.php"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt"></span> Profil</a></li>
        <li><a href=><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-open"></span> Data Alumni</a>

    </ul>
</nav>

<div style="position:absolute;margin-top:100px; margin-left:100px">
  content<br/>
  content<br/>
  content<br/>
  content<br/>
  content<br/>
  content<br/>
  content<br/>
  content<br/>
  content<br/>
  content<br/>
  content<br/>
  content<br/>
  content<br/>
  content<br/>
  content<br/>
  content<br/>
  content<br/>
  content<br/>
  content<br/>
  content<br/>
  content<br/>
  content<br/>
  content<br/>
  content<br/>
  content<br/>
  content<br/>
  content<br/>
  content<br/>
  content<br/>
  content<br/>
  content<br/>
  content<br/>
  </div>
```